# Infinite system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find a stationary distribution of some matrix in probability, so I am looking at a solution for $\pi$ in the equation $\pi A = 0$ where $\pi$ is a row vector and $A$ is an infinite matrix as follows. $\pi$ represents a probability distribution over the infinite state space and hence if a non-zero solution to $\pi A$ exists, then I am looking forward to a solution such that the sum of the elements of $\pi = 1$.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    -6 & 6 & 0 \cdots & \, & \, & \, & 0\\
    1 & -7 & 6 & 0 &\cdots & \,  & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & -8 & 6 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \\
    0 & \dots & \dots & \,  && n-1 & -n-5 \\
    \vdots & \cdots & & & & & \vdots
    \end{bmatrix}$$

So I have $-k-5$ as the diagonal element for the $k^\text{th}$ row, $6$ above the diagonal and $k$ as the element below the diagonal element for the $k^\text{th}$ row.

> May I know how I can solve for $\pi$? If $A$ were a finite matrix of size $n$, I understand that then $A$ is invertible and $\pi = 0$ is the unique solution.

Comment: What is $\pi$ ?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Sorry, added info in the question.

Comment: You can see that the solution space is at most $1$ dimensional because the solution space of the first two equations is $1$ dimensional.  Then it's easy to see that a solution to all the equations exists because the equations are triangular so the solution can be defined inductively, but I don't know if there's a closed form for the coordinates of that solution or not.

Answer (score 2):

$\pi$ is parallel to the row $R=[a_0=1,a_1,a_2,\cdots]$ with

$a_{k}=\dfrac{6^k}{k!}$.

Then $\pi=e^{-6}R$.

EDIT. Answer to the OP.

Let $B_n$ be the matrix composed with the first $n$ rows of $A^T$ and the first $n+1$ columns of $A^T$.

Then $\ker(B_n)$ has dimension $1$ and admits the basis $[a_0,\cdots,a_n]^T$.

Comment: I see, thanks, may I know why $\pi $ is parallel to $R$?